# How to edit a working set or maybe there are other tools for fast filtering?

Tags: eclipse

I have a lot of projects in my package view with a lot of resources(.java, .xml, .vm, .js, and so on) but I work only with several of them and the list could change with the time. I need a tool that allow me to filter quickly only selected files("my files") and back to a full projects list. I thought I can do that using working sets but I can't find a way to add and delete files from an existing working set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to `Window->Customize Perspective`. In **Command And Groups Availability** tab enable **Window Working Set** option if not enabled. Click OK
2. Go to `Window->Working Sets->Edit`. A dialog will pop up. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> button after selecting any working set.

Comment: That's too inconvenient I'll try to find something else, thanks though.

Comment: Found it! "Working set manipulations" in Customize Perspective. Thanks a lot!